# ng-animate slide without a pre-defined list

Tags: angularjs, css-animations

Most ng-animate slide examples have a predefined list of items to slide through. However, in my case, I don't have a pre-defined list - the next item is got using an ajax call. What method can I use to make a slide transition in such a situation?

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [Angular Carousel](https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel), it's an awesome library that handles AJAX with a buffer, i.e. it loads the next few slides via AJAX and only when needed (i.e. you're three away from the end of the currently loaded slides).